# Mail application alike document soft deletion mechanism

Tags: sql-server, soft-delete

My question is a bit of a logical one. I hope my title is not misleading.

I'm working on a mail application like website where users can send or receive documents.

Documents are kept in a daabase table which holds attributes like Sender, Receiver, DeleteDate, DeleteuserId etc.

Let's look at this scenario.

- A sends Document1 to B.
- Document1 is at A's outbox and B's Inbox
- A wants to delete it from the outbox

At this moment my deletion mechanism kicks in and sets the deletedate and deleteuserId of Document1 to date and Id of A respectively.

Problem is, now the document is logically deleted ( deletedate and deleteuserID are not null anymore) so both A and B can't see it because listing stored procedures don't allow "deleted" items to the list.

What kind of a logic should be implemented in order to let B see it and A don't ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best. but if you update the sender_id in the document table, then it will lost the connection with the document table. But if there is a some logic then you will create some other errors.